# How do I safely use ThreadLocal caches in Actors?

Tags: scala, lift

My app ends up doing a lot of background processing via Actors, specifically loading Mapper instances and then doing some work upon them.  It's very repetitive and I'd like to cache some of these lookups across my Actor code.

I'd typically use a ThreadLocal for this.  However, since the thread initialization is handled by the Actor thread pool, it seems like the only place to initialize and subsequently clear the ThreadLocal would be in the actor's PartialFunction which receives incoming messages.

What I'm doing now is to create another method in my Actor, like this:

```
override def aroundUpdates[T](fn: => T) : T = {
  clientCache.init {
    fn
  }
}
```

Where the `init` method handles clearing the ThreadLocal in a finally block.  I don't like this approach because aroundUpdates only exists for the purpose of setting up the cache and it smells like a code smell.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You don't need to use thread-locals**: during a single reaction, you *are* running in a single thread. Hence you could just use a normal `var`. What's more, because your reactions are *sequential* and the actor subsystem manages synchronization for you, you *could* (If you want) access the state from different reactions:

```
def act = loop {
  var state : String = null

  def foo = state = "Hello"
  def bar = { println(state + " World"); state = null }
  def baz = println(state + " Oxbow")
  react {
    case MsgA => foo; bar
    case MsgB => baz
  }

}
```

Hence thread locals make no sense whatsoever to use in your own reactions!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have concluded that my design is way too complicated (a pool of actors calling methods outside of their definition scope) and needs to be cleaned up.